# Combining observables in RxJava, is there a better way to do this?

Tags: rx-java

I'm learning RxJava. I'm retrieving film information from two API.

- The first API (`Api1` class) receives an `id` and returns a JSON (`Api1Dto` class):

`{ id : "123456", title : "Top Secret", api2Id : "7787" }`

- The second API (`Api2` class) receives an `api2id` and returns a JSON (`Api2Dto` class):

`{api2Id : "58582", "director" : "Peter Jackson" }`

I want, from an `id`, compose a structure with all those fields (`Film` class):

`{ id: "123456", title : "Muahaha", api2Id : "5552", director : "Uncle Joe" }`

I have this code:

```
 public Observable<Film> getById(final String id) {
        return api1.getById(id).map(new Func1<Api1Dto, Film>() {
            @Override
            public Film call(Api1Dto dto1) {
                Film film = new Film();
                film.id = dto1.id;
                film.title = dto1.title;
                film.api2Id = dto1.api2Id;
                return film;
            }
        }).flatMap(new Func1<Film, Observable<Film>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<Film> call(final Film film) {
                return api2.getById(film.api2Id).map(new Func1<Api2Dto, Film>() {
                    @Override
                    public Film call(Api2Dto dto2) {
                        film.director = dto2.director;
                        return film;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

It works, but I wonder if this is the correct way to do it or exists a better/more elegant solution using functions that RxJava provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little better "elegant" way : `flatMap` can do the `map` job for you.

```
 public Observable<Film> getById(final String id) {
    return api1.getById(id).map(dto1 -> {
            Film film = new Film();
            film.id = dto1.id;
            film.title = dto1.title;
            film.api2Id = dto1.api2Id;
            return film;
          }).flatMap(film -> api2.getById(film.api2Id), (film, dto2) -> {
                                      film.director = dto2.director;
                                      return film;

          });
}
```